# Insert a "sub-bullet" inside a bullet using Google Docs API

Tags: python, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have a Python application using the Google Docs API where I need to perform an operation such as the following. Imagine I have this structure on a document:

```
1. Text 1
    1.1 Internal text
2. Text 2
```

I want to insert a text below but inside the bullet of `Text 1`, and have the resulting structure as:

```
1. Text 1
    1.1 New text
    1.2 Internal text
2. Text 2
```

I have tried to use the `insertText` text request to insert `\n\tNew text` on the location after `Text 1`, but it resulted in:

```
1. Text 1
2.    New text
    2.1 Internal text
```

I would like to know what I can do to have the desired structure using the Google Docs API. Could anyone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

### Try this:

You can use the `insertText` from Docs API in inserting text in the sub-bullet. You just need to locate the index of the first bullet line.

Based from your existing document structure you can use the code below

### Code:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google.oauth2 import service_account

#Authentication
#Service Credentials
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = '/content/credentials.json'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents']
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

#Document API build
service = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=creds)

# Document Id
document_id = "Document ID here"
new_text = 'New Text'

#Retrieve the current content of the document
document = service.documents().get(documentId=document_id).execute()
#Search for the last index of first line
content_index = document['body']['content'][2]['startIndex']

requests = [
    {
        'insertText': {
            'location': {
                'index': content_index
            },
            'text': new_text + '\n'
        }
    }
]
result = service.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=document_id, body={'requests': requests}).execute()
```

Note:
We may differ on authentication steps since I am using `service account` in connecting the google docs API

### Output:

[image]

### References:

[Inserting text](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/move-text#inserting_text)

[Google Docs API](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest)

Comment: In fact I would like to insert a text with one more level of nesting despite the presence or not of another bullet with the desired level. So, I would like to know how to insert `New text` even if `Internal text` doesn't exist. I modified my question to make that clear. But thanks for your solution anyway, it gave me a new option that I will try to adapt to achieve what I want. I clarified my question to make it clearer.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad my solution gave you an option to your issue. I would like to support you. But the issue of your comment is a new document structure, and that is different from your initial question. So can you post it as a new question by including the detailed information? Because when your initial question is changed, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as a new question, other users including me can try to solve it.